# Auditing a SortedSet property using Javers gives java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, hibernate, javers

I'm trying to audit a SortedSet property using Javers but I keep getting the below exception when I try to do a commit.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.javers.core.metamodel.object.InstanceId cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1188)
at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:531)
at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
```

This doesn't happen when I try to audit a property of type Set instead of SortedSet. 
(Also, Animal class implements Comparable and method compareTo())
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A basic (ie. unsorted) `Set` simply holds elements. A [SortedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) applies an ordering to those elements and you must supply the ordering in some way. For example, by ensuring the elements implement the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface (for natural ordering) or by supplying a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

In your case, it looks like the sorting comparison requires comparing `InstanceIds`. (Either because you are adding them directly to the set, or the elements you are adding have `InstanceIds`.) As [InstanceId](https://javers.org/javadoc_3.x/org/javers/core/metamodel/object/InstanceId.html) does not implement `Comparable`, you get an error.

(If you supply a bit more of your code, eg. set creation and adding to it, it may be clearer what the cause of your error is.)

Comment: I'm not adding InstanceIds to the set directly as InstanceIds are created by Javers itself when storing the snapshots in the database. It stores the entity properties in the database using InstanceId objects and does the comparing of each version of the property I'm trying to audit using Javers.

Comment: OK. I think I need to see more code then. What are your classes? How do you initiate the JSON conversion, etc.

Comment: So how InstanceId objects land in your SortedSet?